# Unable to access folder with backslash in the foldername in hdfs

Tags: hdfs

I have created a folder in hdfs using spark with a '\' in its name. How to delete that folder or access it? I am unable to do that.

I tried creating this file in spark 
`\user\prime\temp\nipun\cddsIdNotinPsdw` 
and it created the below one in hdfs 
It took \t as tab and \n as next line in hdfs
Here is the name of the folder that it shows in my hdfs, and I am unable to delete that

```
\user\prime     emp  
ipun\cddsIdNotinPsdw
```

Now I am unable to delete this in hdfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to do with command line for hdfs. I had to write a scala program inorder to delete it, by getting the file object.

Answer (score 1):

If it's about linux just write part of name you can then press key TAB or as example this is my directory
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4096 Jan 12 08:28 lopa \popa 
This is how i delete:    rmdir "lopa \popa"/

Your example to delete is 
rmdir "\\user\\prime emp ipun\\cddsldNotinPsdw"/

Comment: this is the name of the folder that it shows in my hdfs \user\prime     emp
ipun\cddsIdNotinPsdw. I have edited the question, can you please help me out

Comment: Hey, I have updated my question, please have a look, the above did not helped

Comment: It showed me this error hdfs dfs -ls "\\user\\prime emp ipun\\cddsldNotinPsdw"/
ls: Illegal file pattern: Illegal Unicode escape sequence near index 2

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: Its red had linux

Comment: If is  redhat you can't use rmdir command? Your command maybe have other syntax which i don't know

Comment: I gues you used on two backslash when you tried delete right?

Comment: I used to list this folder in hdfs and its not giving me error,

Comment: hdfs dfs -ls "\\user\\prime emp ipun\\cddsldNotinPsdw"/